# int array and double array - difference

Tags: java, arrays

What the difference between the `int` **array** and the new `double` **array** in the following code?

```
public class TestTwoReview {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ducky[] = { 21, 16, 86, 21, 3 };
        int sum = 0;

        for (int counter = 0; counter <ducky.length; counter++) {
            // adding all numbers in array
            sum += ducky[counter];
        }

        System.out.println("the sum of array is " + sum);

        double[] scores = new double[10];
        double total = 0;
        double average;

        for (int index = 0; index < scores.length; index++)
            total += scores[index];

        average = total / scores.length;
        System.out.println("the average is " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-integer-and-double

Comment: your `int` array has pre filled values which you can access and give you a result. a `new` array has no values in it and therefore every reading access deliveres `null`. primitives deliver `0`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer that's not true because it's a double primitive array.

Comment: so  what is the purpose and what situations would  i need to use a new array

Comment: @JoshuaCarpentier If you plan to compute the **average of the first data** you don't need to do the second part. Remove it and add `double average = ((double) sum) / ducky.length;`. The `average` will correctly be `14.7 = 147 / 10`. Be aware of the explicit `double` **cast**, else you divide integers which are always rounded. The result then would be `14` instead of `14.7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't really look like it's doing something *useful*. Maybe that is what confuses you the most. Especially the second part essentially does nothing.

---

### Analysis

Let's take a closer look at it. The `int` array `ducky` contains some data. You iterate all its elements and **sum them up**. Thus `sum` correctly contains the accumulated value of all entries, which should be `147` I guess.

The second part initializes a `double` array with place for `10` elements.

```
double[] scores = new double[10];
```

As `double` is a **primitive datatype** the array will be **pre-filled** with the value `0.0` at every entry:

```
scores[0] => 0.0
scores[1] => 0.0
scores[2] => 0.0
...
scores[9] => 0.0
```

Next you analogously iterate all those entries and sum them up in the variable `total`:

```
total += scores[index];
```

However since `scores[index]` is `0.0` at every entry, the sum will also be `0.0`. Next you compute the average

```
average = total / scores.length;
```

If we input values we have

```
average = 0.0 / 10
        = 0.0
```

So `average` is also `0.0`.

All in all the second part misses some meaningful data, else it would  first compute the **sum** **too** and next also the average.

---

### Difference

But what is the difference if we even assume that `scores` would be filled with some **meaningful** data?

Well, the only difference is that it also allows **decimal values**, nothing more, nothing less.

For example you could create it like

```
double[] scores = { 1.7, 2.3, 6.12, 9.1, 2.0 };
```

The sum `total` will then be `21.22` and the average is `2.122`.

The `int` array is not capable of doing this, it only accepts **non decimal values** (integers).

Comment: so it useful when want to input values

Comment: Upvote as nice explanation. I would have added in a simple `scores[0] = 1.5;` and so on if the OP wishes to actually put values into that array, the way they initialised it.

Comment: @JoshuaCarpentier Yeah, the second part (like the first part) successfully computes the **sum** of the given data. And the second part even computes the **average**. However you could also compute average with `int` data, that's not an issue. The only difference is that `double[]` accepts `double` values (decimals) and `int[]` only `int` (integers, non-decimals).